# How to use bitmask_operators.hpp with namespace and classes

Tags: c++11, templates, bit-fields, bitmask, enum-class

I want to use C++11 `enum class` as bitfields and find a nice approach [here](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/using-enum-classes-as-bitfields.html).

But I stuck, if my enum class declaration is not in global namespace but in custom namespace or inside of a class instead. E.g.:

```
#define ENABLE_BIT_OPERATORS(E) template<> struct enable_bitmask_operators<E> { static constexpr bool enable=true; };

// anonymous namespace
namespace {
enum class Ean {
    None = 0x00,
    Bit0 = 0x01,
    Bit1 = 0x02,
    Bit2 = 0x04,
    Bit3 = 0x08,
};
ENABLE_BIT_OPERATORS(Ean)
} // anonymous namespace

// custom namespace
namespace Custom {
enum class Ecn {
    None = 0x00,
    Bit0 = 0x01,
    Bit1 = 0x02,
    Bit2 = 0x04,
    Bit3 = 0x08,
};
ENABLE_BIT_OPERATORS(Ecn)
} // custom namespace

// inside class in global namespace
class MyclassGN {
public:
    enum class Ecgn {
        None = 0x00,
        Bit0 = 0x01,
        Bit1 = 0x02,
        Bit2 = 0x04,
        Bit3 = 0x08,
    };
    ENABLE_BIT_OPERATORS(Ecgn)
};

// inside class in anonymous namespace
namespace {
class MyclassAN {
public:
    enum class Ecan {
        None = 0x00,
        Bit0 = 0x01,
        Bit1 = 0x02,
        Bit2 = 0x04,
        Bit3 = 0x08,
    };
    ENABLE_BIT_OPERATORS(Ecan)
};
} // anonymous namespace

// inside class in custom namespace
namespace Custom {
class MyclassGN {
public:
    enum class Ecgn {
        None = 0x00,
        Bit0 = 0x01,
        Bit1 = 0x02,
        Bit2 = 0x04,
        Bit3 = 0x08,
    };
    ENABLE_BIT_OPERATORS(Ecgn)
};
} // custom namespace
```

This always gives me errors:

```
error: specialization of 'template<class E> struct enable_bitmask_operators' in different namespace
```

until I place my template specialization to the same namespace as the template `enable_bitmask_operators` in `bitmask_operators.hpp` is located (global namespace in this case).

But I want to have my specialization close to my enum class declaration.

In the mentioned [article](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/using-enum-classes-as-bitfields.html), this problem is also commented by Jay Miller and it seems that he provides a solution. But I failed to follow his hints to solve this in `bitmask_operators.hpp`.

Example code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70f8ec72221dfb46).

**Edit / partially solved:** I meanwhile, I got it work (just a dump copy & paste issue and cryptic error messages ;-). I'd just updated my [example code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a05fed01974d762f) by applying Jay Millers constexpr function solution.

But there is still an issue when declaring the enum class inside of a class. The issue raises, when I add a ctor to my class, like:

```
class MyclassGN {
public:
    enum class Ecgn {
        None = 0x00,
        Bit0 = 0x01,
        Bit1 = 0x02,
        Bit2 = 0x04,
        Bit3 = 0x08,
    };
    ENABLE_BIT_OPERATORS(Ecgn)
    explicit MyclassGN(Ecgn e_) {}
};
```

Then I got an error:

```
enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function 'bool MyclassGN::enable_bitmask_operators(MyclassGN::Ecgn)' is not a literal type
```

Well, I fixed this by adding `static` keyword:

```
class MyclassGN {
public:
    enum class Ecgn {
        None = 0x00,
        Bit0 = 0x01,
        Bit1 = 0x02,
        Bit2 = 0x04,
        Bit3 = 0x08,
    };
    static ENABLE_BIT_OPERATORS(Ecgn)
    explicit MyclassGN(Ecgn e_) {}
};
```

But the next issue raises when I try to use the bitmask operators, e.g.:

```
class MyclassGN {
public:
    enum class Ecgn {
        None = 0x00,
        Bit0 = 0x01,
        Bit1 = 0x02,
        Bit2 = 0x04,
        Bit3 = 0x08,
    };
    static ENABLE_BIT_OPERATORS(Ecgn)
    explicit MyclassGN(Ecgn e_): e(e_) {
        e |= Ecgn::Bit3;
    }
private:
    Ecgn e;
};
```

I got an error:

```
no match for 'operator|=' (operand types are 'MyclassGN::Ecgn' and 'MyclassGN::Ecgn')
```

Updated example which shows the error is located [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2447896731d8759b).

Comment: *"But I failed to follow his hints"* Can you show us your attempt, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example code, based on Anthony Williams' `bitmask_operators.hpp` and also applied Jay Millers suggestion (constexpr function instead of template<> struct) to fix the namespace issue is located [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0078ec798365a21).

Note that when declaring the enum class inside of a class, the constexpr function needs to be preceded by the `friend` keyword (as dyp suggested in the comment below). Example:

```
class Myclass {
public:
    enum class E {
        None = 0x00,
        Bit0 = 0x01,
        Bit1 = 0x02,
        Bit2 = 0x04,
        Bit3 = 0x08,
    };
    friend ENABLE_BIT_OPERATORS(E)
};
```

Comment: You can use a friend function inside of the class (example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eecfd85c6e1089e0 ), not sure how to do it with one single macro though, except for declaring that function at namespace-scope and using qualified-ids to refer to the enumeration. But I dislike macros anyway, so having both `constexpr bool enable_bitmask_operators` and `friend constexpr enable_bitmask_operators` would be fine by me.

Comment: Yep, using `friend` keyword do the job.